# ARM assembly code can not save register value into another register?

Tags: assembly, arm

I have a strange behavior here.
I have written a simple function that puts a value from specific address into two registers. It look like this:

```
.globl GetCurrentCounter
GetCurrentCounter:
  push {lr}
  bl GetTimerAddress
  mov r2,r0
  ldrd r0,r1,[r2,#4]
  pop {pc}
```

only it doesn't work, but if I omit the step where I assign the r0 to r2 and perform ldrd directly it works:

```
.globl GetCurrentCounter
GetCurrentCounter:
  push {lr}
  bl GetTimerAddress
  ldrd r0,r1,[r0,#4]
  pop {pc}
```

I don't get why is it so.

The function GetTimerAddress:

```
.globl GetTimerAddress
GetTimerAddress:
  ldr r0,=0x20003000
  mov pc,lr
```

Comment: Note that `[r0,#4]` is not 8 byte aligned, thus `ldrd` causes undefined behaviour. Perhaps try `ldm` instead?

Comment: are you wanting to read 64 bits at offset 0x00 or 32 bits at offset 0x4?

Comment: hmm, the ldrd pseudo code in the ARM ARM implies that it does two separate loads if the lower three bits of the address is not '000'.  I guess I would have to try it to be sure.

Comment: @fuz I am not sure I understand you, but, the thing is that the counter is at address 0x20003004 and it actually has 8 bytes. The thing is, it works with ldrd, but only if I use r0 (the timer base address) directly. If I try to assign it to r2 first, then it fails to work and I don't see why.

Comment: @old_timer I want to read 64 bits into two registers (as each can hold only 32).. at the address mentioned above..

Comment: @stove The address `0x20003004` is not dividable by eight and thus not eight byte aligned. `ldrd` is undefined for insufficiently aligned operands.

Comment: @fuz ldm is the same. If I use r0 directly "add r0,#4" and then "ldm r0,{r0,r1}" it works, but if I try to use e.g r2 like so "add r2,r0,#4" and then "ldm r2,{r0,r1}" then it doesnt work... as I said, I am a newbie, so I don't understand why it doesnt matter that it is not 8B aligned in one case and does matter in the other...

Comment: @old_timer answer above

Comment: @stove For ldrd, the address needs to be 8 byte aligned because the manual says so. Seriously, read the manual. Still, I'm not entirely sure what your problem is.Which `ldm` variant did you you use exactly? Is this ARM or thumb code?

Comment: @fuz I dont know how else to formulate my question. I tried both ldm variants and as I wrote, one worked and the other didn't. The only difference being the attempt to use (or not) one more register to store the address of a timer device.
I follow [this](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/ok04.html) tutorial, but I always try to 'play' with the solutions to better understand it. Right now I don't want to read the manual because I wouldn't understand half of it, but after this series, I might do it if I find myself intrigued enough.

Comment: @fuz is suposed to be [ARMv6](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/armv6.html)

Comment: @stove Please read the official manual (e.g. [this one](http://115.28.165.193/down/arm/arch/ARMv6-M_Architecture_Reference_Manual.pdf)) instead of something your professor cooked up. The ldrd instruction is undefined for unaligned addresses, which is a limitation described in that manual.

Comment: @fuz thanks for the link. Still dunno why this "add r2,r0,#4" and then "ldm r2,{r0,r1}" doesn't work... Hopefully I figure it out in the manu...